# Is there a command to flag and clean different messages that have the same translation in a po file?

Tags: gettext

Is there a command to flag and clean different messages that have the same translation in a GetText po file ?

```
#: templates/translations.html:7161
msgid "Straightedges"
msgstr "Règles de précision"

#: templates/translations.html:11697
msgid "Straight hemostats"
msgstr "Règles de précision"
```

Is there a way to wipe all the translations in that case ?

Comment: Please create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem so others can best assist you.

Comment: There is no such command. But what do you want to achieve? Really wiping out/deleting such entries would make your translation incomplete. Can you clarify your goal?

Comment: I would like to remove most of the erroneous translations from a GetText file. Those were added using a faulty translation memory.

Comment: @KristopherIves The question was complete. Everything else would have been noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Perl script for that task:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

use Locale::PO;

die "usage: $0 POFILE\n" unless $ARGV[0];

binmode 'STDOUT', ':utf8';
my $entries = Locale::PO->load_file_asarray($ARGV[0], 'UTF-8')
    or die "$ARGV[0]: $!\n";

my %seen;

foreach my $entry (@$entries) {
    ++$seen{$entry->dequote($entry->msgstr)};
}
foreach my $entry (@$entries) {
    my $msgstr = $entry->dequote($entry->msgstr);
    #next if $seen{$msgstr} > 1;
    $entry->msgstr("") if $seen{$msgstr} > 1;
    print $entry->dump;
}
```

You need the Perl library `Locale-PO` for that.  You can install it with one the command `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Locale::PO'`. Omit the `sudo` if you don't need it.

If you really want to delete the entries with duplicate translations, then uncomment the line with `next`.  My version just discards the translation which is most probably what you really want.

The solution oversimplifies a little bit. It does not support entries with plural forms or message contexts but you probably don't need them anyway.

Comment: @PierreS I have rewritten my answer.  The new version now really deletes the duplicates like you had requested.

Comment: @PierreS When you reply to somebody in a comment, then address them like here with the at-sign and the user name. Otherwise that user won't be notified.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guido. This answers the question perfectly. It is indeed about discarding rather than removing the duplicate translations.